# Appendix numbering issue

Tags: numbering, appendices

I am trying to obtain the following structure (in terms of titles) :

> ```
> Chapter 5 : Last Title
> Annex 
>   A - Section1Annex
>   B - Section2Annex
> ```

where `Chapter 5` and `Annex` are referenced as `\chapter` title.

I managed to "remove" the chapter numbering for the Annex (with `addcontentsline` and `chapter*{Annex}` inside a custom made command, "`\myChap`), so, **no problem** on that side.

Then, on below the code I wrote :

```
\chapter{Last Title}
\myChap{Annex}
\appendix
\section{Section1Annex}
\section{Section2Annex}
```

However, it displays the following structure:

> ```
> Chapter 5 : Last Title
> Annex 
>   0.1 - Section1Annex
>   0.2 - Section2Annex
> ```

**My problem :**

How can I switch these section numbering from `0.1` (resp.`0.2`) to `A` (resp. `B`). I am having difficulties to deal with the `\appendix` environment.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you want to have unnumbered chapters, use `\chapter*{Annex}` instead. And for standard document classes, `\appendix` will switch to alpha 'numbering' of its sections. Most proably, you will have to say `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}` after saying `\appendix`, in order to get rid off the `0` numbering for appendix sections

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am already using `chapter*` inside the new command I created \myChap. I know how to have unnumbered chapters, that's not my problem.

Comment: Thats a common thing. Appendices are supposed to be chapters of its own, not subsections in a single chapter.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : You solved my problem with `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}`, thank you very much.

Comment: @Johannes_B: If it's a book or report, you're right

Comment: @Johannes_B : could you provide me some documentation demonstrating/establishing  that "common thing"? I didn't know about that. If you have 10 annexes and only 3 chapters for the main report, you would have 3 + 10 chapters inside your final document? It would look unbalanced, wouldn't it? I first thought it would be better to have 3 + 1 chapters, am I wrong there?

Comment: @enigmator: I think, Johannes meant, that you brought self into *troubles* by using a unnumbered chapter as `\appendix` leadin and then `\section` as sub level, whereas `\appendix` obviously *expects* `\chapter` for your documentclass.

Comment: Look what @ChristianHupfer wrote: «If it's a book or report, you're right». They usually have more than 3 chapters.

Comment: But three chapters and ten annexes seems quite odd, to be honest. Can you group them somehow?

Comment: @Johannes_B Unfortunately, my report has only 3 chapters but several documentation to refers, I may have more than 3 annexes, making the report unbalanced imo. I am open to any suggestion/documentation to help me improving this setup anyway. :)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, as written above, the problem is solved. However I can't accept any answer in comments. Thank you for your help anyway and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution suggestion, since lacking a MWE, `\mychap` is unknown and not used in here.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}%

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{The last one}


\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Annex}%
\chapter*{\appendixname}

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}%
% Eventually a \cleardoublepage here
 \cleardoublepage
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\section{AnnexSectionOne}
\section{AnnexSectionTwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, as said, your solution in comments above solved my issue. Have a nice day!

Comment: `\phantomsection` isn't necessary in later versions of `hyperref` (after of 2009/11/25 v6.79h). In fact this example works better without it, because the link points directly to `Annex`. (remove it and observe)

Comment: @skpblack: Thanks, I just tested it. Nevertheless, there might be situations, where it is still necessary, so I have grown accustomed to use it as much as possible.